# Upload file into var/www/uploads and make it accessible

Tags: php, file-upload, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to upload a file, and that part is ok, but then I can't access it in my web browser without typling:

```
sudo chmod 777 filename
```

I used php command:

```
chmod($targetfile, 755);
```

but it doesn't do it. How to get this working?

Comment: Change it in your config files

Comment: Can you explain how?

Comment: With something like notepad or sublime text

Comment: Really? Is that your answer?